# About horizontal nav bars

Tags: html, css, navigation

My code is simple, I just want a navigation bar that shows it's links horizontally. Should be very easy, but I've never been able to do it. Examples found online go like this:

```
<!-- Navigator -->
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Anchor 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Anchor 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Anchor 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
/* So it's cantered on top */
#nav {
margin:0 50%; 
position:fixed;

}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position: absolute;
}   

#nav ul li {
float:left;
}
```

As far as I know, this SHOULD work, can someone please exlain me what's wrong? Removing the position:fixed of #nav turns it horizontal, but it wont stick to the top of my viewport.

Comment: use divs as far as i know ul and lis are for vertical menu bars

Comment: Mr.Coder, you can use Ul and lis for horizontal menus and as far as i have seen most websites do use list items for menu(horizontal and vertical) You could simply set the width of the ul to 100%; float:left; text-align:center and set the li to display:inline-block.

Comment: @Mr.coder: That’s just nonsense. HTML is there to mark up the contents (and using ul/li/a for a navigation is a broadly used pattern) – how you format it then is a totally different matter, and one of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just over complicated things. Get rid of all the positions you have used because you do not need them at all. I just mocked something up on codepen for you to have a look: http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/mhgze.
The following css is all you need and the menu will be responsive to a certain extend. Let me know if you want to do something in addition to how it is displayed.

```
#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}   

#nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: This worked, I just added fixed position to the bar to make stick. Thank you ramesh.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the position:absolute from the ul.  I do not think it's needed to accomplish your goal.

```
#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of two reasons :
1. The margin
3. I think the list items are being set to absolute (inherited). Set it to static.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/txDSa/

```
#nav {
position:fixed;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0 !important;
padding:0;
position: static;
}   

#nav ul li {
margin:0 ;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the the position absolute http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/Jn9P6/

```
#nav {
margin:0 auto;
width:300px;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}   

#nav ul li {
float:left;
padding-left: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* So it's cantered on top */
#nav {
text-align:center;
}

#nav ul {
display:inline;
}   

#nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
}
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4EJHF/

Basically you want the text aligned to center on your nav element. Then your unordered list should be displayed inline. Finally, your list elements shoud be displayed inline-block.

There is another method with two floats, but you would need to manually center the navigation:

```
#nav ul {
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
}   

#nav ul li {
float:left;
padding:10px;
}
```